# Queryset for specific child class (NOT abstract model)

Tags: django, postgresql, inheritance, orm

How do I get a queryset of specific child classes? It doesn't look like going through `related_name` is the answer. Using Django 3.2.6 btw.

Here is my setup:

```py
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = # char field

class Question(models.Model):
    # a quiz has many questions
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name = '%(class)s')
    # etc...

class TFQuestion(Question):
    is_true = models.BooleanField(...)

class MCQuestion(Question):
    n_choices = models.IntegerField(...)
```

What I want is to get a queryset of just MC Questions and process them as such.

I feel the need to emphasize that Question is NOT abstract. So the question model has its own `related_name` but the specified `'%(class)s'` pattern does not seem to propagate down to the child classes. All the other threads I've seen suggest using that pattern but **it only works for abstract models!** not when using multi-table inheritance.

From what I've seen, I **can't** just do:

```py
quiz1 = Quiz.objects.get(id=1)

# this works; returns queryset of Question objects
allquestions = quiz1.question.all()

# doesn't work
all_mcqs = quiz1.mcquestion.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
MCQuestion.objects.filter(quiz=quiz1)
```

For inheritance of a concrete model, Django will make tables for the `Question`, `TFQuestion` and `MCQuestion`s, so three tables. The `MCQuestion` will have a "hidden" `OneToOneField` to `Question`.

Answer (score 1):

### self answer (kinda)

a couple workarounds i've seen, but jankier than just using a related_name:

A.) using classname__isnull:

```py
quiz1 = Quiz.objects.get(id=1)

# get quiz1's MCQuestions as Questions
qs1 = quiz1.question.filter(mcquestion__isnull = False)
# returns: <QuerySet[<Question>,...]>
qs1.first().mcquestion.n_choices
```

B.) using `InheritanceManager` and classname__isnull:

```py
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Question(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = InheritanceManager()

# django shell

quiz1 = Quiz.objects.get(id=1)

# get quiz1's MCQuestions as MCQuestions
qs1 = quiz1.question.select_subclasses().filter(mcquestion__isnull = False)
# returns: <InheritanceQuerySet[<Question>,...]>
qs1.first().n_choices
```